# Human-readable representations in protobuf-net

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, human-readable

Does [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) have any APIs to dump a protobuf into human readable form? I was hoping for something like [TextFormat](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.text_format.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, no. I'm in two minds as to whether it is worthwhile adding; in my mind, this defeats most of the benefits of protocol buffers.

However, since Jon's version is a port of the java version you should find that it is feature compatible, so it should exist there.

Comment: Thanks. Agreed that it would defeat the purpose of protobuf if it were used for serialization. However sometimes it's useful to be able to be able to dump protobuf objects for debugging purposes. I was thinking about writing a protobuf inspector for Fiddler so that I'd be able to read protobuf data over the wire when troubleshooting protocol issues.

Comment: @pepsi - I just throw them into JSON

Answer (score 1):

there is one for java. the build.toString() method returns a string representation but you'll loose the serialization.